Пытаюсь с помощью метода keyboard.write() отправить на citrix текст из буффера, но выдаёт (???)
На работе используем Citrix, в котором администратор заблокировал копирование между локальной тачкой и удалённой. Так как вся важная инфа на удалёнке, то копировать из локалки не криминально. Пришла в голову идея с помощью keyboard.write копировать значения из буффера обмена и вставлять в удалёнку. Английский текст вставляется без проблем, даже если в перемешку с русским и раскладка включена другая, но русский текст на удалёнке всегда отображается как "????", хотя на локалке всё хорошо отображает и вставляется.
Может нужно какие-то до опции проставить?
from pynput import keyboard
import keyboard as kb
import win32clipboard
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

def on_activate():
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    print(data)
    test = "Проверка"
    kb.write(test,exact="utf-8")

def for_canonical(f):
    return lambda k: f(l.canonical(k))

hotkey = keyboard.HotKey(
    keyboard.HotKey.parse('<ctrl>+b'),
    on_activate)

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
        on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release)) as l:
    l.join()


Также хочу добавить, что локалка на win11, а удалёнка на win10. Может ли быть из-за этого проблема?
